# Call web service from javascript

Tags: magento2, javascript, web-services

I could call web service from block with code below : `$jsonObject=json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.testservice.com:50001/Services/Magento.asmx/getPayer?input=".$datasJson));`

How can i call service from java script? I tried with code below, but it's all not work.

```
urlBuilder.createUrl('http://wsq.starcosmosgroup.com:50001/Services/Magento.asmx/getPayer?input=', {}),
JSON.stringify({
     parameter1: 'data1',
     parameter2: 'data2'
}
```

**UPDATE :**

I tried to get the data from service for change the billing address data in checkout page. I adding the code below, and add 'jquery' to the define, but it made the other function error, so how can i get the data from the service?

billing-address.js :

```
getBill: function (prefix) {
   payload = {
        parameter1: prefix,
        parameter2: 'data'
   };
   url = "http://www.testservice.com:50001/Services/Magento.asmx/getPayer?input="+JSON.stringify(payload);

   alert(url);
   $.get(url, function(response) {
        data = response;
        alert(response);
   });
   return data;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest for you two ways:

1) Magento Ajax > Magento controller > Call the external server

In this case, we need to build the Magento controller. We can use a buit-in class `Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl` to work with HTTP protocol.

2) Magento Ajax > Call the external server directly.

We will have an issue with CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing). So, in this case, make sure the external server allows accessing from your Magento server.

---

We simply use `$.ajax`, `$.get`, `$.post` for Ajax call.

Comment: i tried `payload = {
                    parameter1: prefix,
                    parameter2: 'test'
                };

                $.post("http://www.testservice.com:50001/Services/Magento.asmx/getPayer?input=".JSON.stringify(payload), function(response) {
                    data = response;
                });
                return data;` but it's not work, am i doing something wrong in my code?

Comment: `$.post` is for POST. What do you want in this case?

Comment: When i checked the console, there's error `Cannot read property 'post' of undefined`

Comment: Did you add jquery to require? One more, do you want to post data to the server? Don't want to get the data?

Comment: No, i dont add any require thing in the js, and i want to post data then get the response data, should i use get not post?

Comment: Should add jQuery: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer/view.phtml#L48 in your template. And then, you can use `$.post` and `$.get`.

Comment: If i add the jquery in js define, will it be the same?

Comment: Yes, it will be the same. Should update your question with the full code. It's better for us to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: can you please check my update?